# Can't get page search to advance to next object when ENTER is pressed

Tags: jquery, enter

This page search I wrote works fine, except that I can't get it to advance to the next object in the search_results when ENTER is pressed. I think my problem lies in the object_number variable. Any suggestions? Thanks.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="search-page-container">
Search names<br><input id="search-page" type="text" />
<div id="search-result"></div>
<div id="result-up"><img src="image/down-arrow.png"></div>
<div id="result-down"><img src="image/up-arrow.png"></div>
</div>
```

This is my JQuery. On keyup, all objects with the class ".search-drug" are highlighted. Pressing "result-up" and "result-down" works fine. When ENTER is pressed, it goes to the next search_term once, and when pressed again, it starts looping back to the same result.

```js
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#search-page" ).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.which != 13) {var object_number = 0;}
     var search_term = $('#search-page').val();
     var search_count = $(".search-drug:contains('" + search_term + "')").length;
     var search_results = $(".search-drug:contains('" + search_term + "')");
    
     if ((search_count != 0) && (search_term != '')) {
      if (e.which != 13) {
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[0]).offset().top - 165}, 400);
     }
      $(".search-drug:contains('" + search_term + "')").addClass('highlight');
      $('.search-drug:not(:contains('+ search_term +'))').removeClass('highlight');
      document.getElementById('search-result').innerHTML = search_count;
      
      if (e.which == 13) {
       object_number = search_results.index(); 
        if ((object_number <= (search_count - 1)) && (object_number != 0)) {
       object_number--;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
       else {
       object_number = search_count - 1;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
     }
     
      $("#result-up" ).click(function() {
       if (object_number < (search_count - 1)) {
       object_number++;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
       else {
       object_number = 0;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
      })
      
      $("#result-down" ).click(function() {
       if ((object_number <= (search_count - 1)) && (object_number != 0)) {
       object_number--;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
       else {
       object_number = search_count - 1;
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(search_results[object_number]).offset().top - 165}, 0);
       }
     })
    }
     else {
      $(".search-drug").removeClass('highlight');
      document.getElementById('search-result').innerHTML = '';
      $("#result-up").off();
      $("#result-down").off();
     }
    })
    });
```

```css
#search-page-container {
 padding:5px;
 border:3px #D4D0D0 solid;
 border-radius: 6px;
 background-color: #DFDFDF;
 text-align:left;
 position:fixed;
 top:100px;
 right: 3%;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:grey;
 display:inline-block;
 width:190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#search-page-container {
 bottom:77px;
 left: 20px;
 top:auto;
}
}

.highlight {
 background-color:yellow;
}

#search-page {
 width: 90px;
 margin:5px 5px 0 0;
 color:black;
 display:inline-block;
 border:0;
 padding:0 0 0 3px;
}

#search-page-container {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

#search-result {
 width:20px;
 color:black;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 font-size:90%;
 border:0;
 margin:0 3px 0px 3px;
}

#result-up, #result-down {
 cursor:pointer;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="search-page-container">
Search names<br><input id="search-page" type="text" />
<div id="search-result"></div>
<div id="result-up">DOWN</div>
<div id="result-down">UP</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>



<li class="search-drug">Result 1</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 2</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 3</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 4</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 5</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 6</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li class="search-drug">Result 7</li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Okay, I added a snippet

Comment: Cant you just copy the code from result down to where e.wich==13?

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work. Has something to do with the object_number variable not getting set correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. Made a universal variable that mirrors the value of the object_number variable and inserted it in the (e.which == 13) actions.